# send mulitple args to system() in C

Tags: c, linux, args

Assume, I have one line bash script that executes everything it has in arguments

```
#!/bin/bash
$1
```

So, the command `./one_line_script.sh "ls -lh"` works fine. 
Also I have C code, that accepts arguments and send them to my bash script

```
  int main (int argc, char* argv[])
  {
     char command[1000];
     sprintf(command, "/path/to/one_line_script.sh %s", argv[1]);
     system(command);
   return 0;
  }
```

And here I've got a problem, because `./c_program "ls -lh"` returns only `ls` output. It doesn't understand few arguments. How do I need to modify my C code, so it could accept few arguments?

Comment: in you bash script, instead of `$1`, try `$@`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use `fork` and `exec` directly to avoid quoting issues altogether. Consider for example what happens if a `'` is contained within an argument - when doing `sprintf` cmd-line butchering this leads to broken command lines.

```
int pid = fork();

if(pid == 0) {
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", arg1, arg2, arg3, 0);
} else {
    int status=0;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote it in your sprintf too, or bash will only receive one argument :)

```
sprintf(command, "/path/to/one_line_script.sh '%s'", argv[1]);
```

I've added quotes (`'`) around the %s.

You can also use `$@` instead of `$1` in your bash script, so it will take all arguments passed to it.

Comment: it would be more appropriate to fix the script and not the caller.

Comment: That woks fine:) I'll up your answer when I'll got 15 reputation! thank you

Comment: @mosquitos I think you can already validate it (the green tick). You'll get reputation from that :)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
int i;

command[0] = '\0';
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
  strcat (command, argv[i]);

system (command);
```

This should work, but please be aware that it has a lot of security hazards: first of all executing any possible command you get on the command line might allow users to do things they normally aren't allowed to (don't *setuid* your program!). Then the buffer might easily overflow and allow all kinds of stack smashing. So I'd say: only use this program as a learning tool, to learn manipulation of `argc`/`argv` and to begin thinking about security. Don't even compile it!

Comment: doesn't handle spaces?